# Elegant way of doing table sync reports in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join, intersection

So I have my two tables

**TABLE_A**

```
KEYA | VALUE
1    |  1.2
2    |  2.3
3    |  8.3
```

**TABLE_B**

```
KEYB | VALUE
1    |  1.2
3    |  1.6
4    |  5.5
```

And I want to create a report of the sync status between these two tables. I.e. Generate for *each* record the following information:

1. Record X is in TABLE_A but not in TABLE_B
2. Record X is in TABLE_B but not in TABLE_A
3. Record X is present in both tables but differs in VALUE
4. (records synced won't appear in the report)

I don't really need the text (actually, I don't want it). Could be just the values itself:

```
[Table_A.KEYA (if present)]|[Table_A.Value (if present)]|[Table_B.KEYB (if present)]|[Table_B.Value (if present)]
```

The given example tables should yield:

```
|2|2.3| |   |
|3|8.3|3|1.6|
| |   |4|5.5|
```

I'm currently doing that with longs series of joins and minuses all around, but figured that should be quite common for DBs and Oracle possibly have a more elegant (and possibly more efficient) way of doing it. Could anyone shoot some tips?

Thanks a mil!

f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.keya, a.value a_value, b.keyb, b.value b_value
from table_a a
full outer join table_b b
on a.keya = b.keyb
where a.keya IS NULL
or b.keya IS NULL
or (a.value is null and b.value is not null)
or (a.value is not null and b.value is null)
or a.value <> b.value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think joins and minuses are fine :-)

The above example would give something like

```
select *, null, null
from a
where not exists (select keyb
  from b 
  where keyb = a.keya)
union all
select a.*, b.*
from a, b
where a.keya = b.keya
and a.value <> b.value -- please extend if null values are allowed
union all
select null, null, *
from b
where not exists (select keya
  from a
  where keya = b.keyb)
```

It soon gets messy with lots of columns.